# grunt-karma RangeError Maximum error

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, gruntjs, karma-runner

Recently I've wanted to start using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) in order to improve my development workflow. Although I've had some trouble while Grunt up and running. After creating a `package.json` file and a `Grunt file.js` I've tried running a simple test with grunt-karma with no luck.

All I receive is the error

`Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR`

`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I am running node version 10.12
with grunt-cli & grunt versions 0.1.9 and 0.4.1 respectively.

Below is my package file with all of my dev dependancies and my grunt file.

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "crudangular",
"version": "0.0.1",
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "karma": "~0.8.6",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.4.4",
    "phantomjs": "~1.9.1-0"
 }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    karma: {
        unit:{
            configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
        }
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
grunt.registerTask('default',['karma']);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My grunt was working until I removed the node_module folder, and reinstalled it with npm install. Same error now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Someone else had this issue and ask about this on IRC. Reinstalling node.js and npm helped them resolve this issue.**

Also make sure you clear npm cache. 
You can also try to get `npm install grunt-karma` into a temporary directory, then `npm install` in that directory and run the tests using `grunt test`. This way you can make sure it's an issue with the plugin. 
If running the rests fails, please file an issue on the plugin page, state your OS and node version. 
Plugin page: https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma

Comment: Seemed to work, not such what the problem was, thanks though!

Comment: It looks like this is caused by an issue in node 0.8.x. Upgrading to 0.10.x, clearing npm cache and node_modules, and downloading the same version of grunt-karma again should fix the issue. See comment https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/824#issuecomment-22465436

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I accidentaly included angular-mocks in my karma tests. Just remove the import.